# CGPathRef from text

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, core-text, cgpath

How can we get path of particular string? 
I just found out that `CTFontCreatePathForGlyph` will give `CGPathRef` , but its will be the outline of text .
for example the letter 'O' the path i get from the above method is like a circle with in a circle ..
See how we draw the letter 'O' is just one circle.
I hope that the  above details are enough for to understand  my problem.let me know any updates

I need this text path for showing a text drawing animation..

**UPDATE**
please see the below image.(1) shows what i get now..but i need the path like shown in (2)

[image: please see the below image.(1) shows what i get now..but i need the path like shown in (2)]

Comment: do you have find the answer about it?

Comment: No I couldn't find a solution

Comment: As Davyd has explained in his comments, (1) and (2) are totally different paths because they correspond to totally different fonts (and (2) wouldn't even draw as a font because by default fonts are filled and not stroked). So you either need to find a font that suits you, or find a algorithm that simplifies paths, or write from scratch graphic commands to draw the font you want. If you want to animate the drawing, last solution is probably the best, and yes, it is a lot of work.

Comment: Do you solve it? I meet the same problem. And +1 for this question.

Comment: @realsnake I couldnt find a solution yet

Comment: Anybody looking for answer may try this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7402761/cgpathref-from-text#comment8962544_7403175 , but not sure if that will work or not

Answer (score 1):

Any Bezier path, including that one you get from the glyphs, is just a series of connected Bezier curves. What you see on the screen is the result of rendering the path by CGContext. The path can be stroked, in this case you will see just the outline.

Also it can be filled, in this case the internal regions are filled with colour or pattern. Use CGContextFillPath() to fill your path with colour. Winding rules define how to fill the path if it has intersecting zones.

Comment: if i use CGContextFillPath() it is will jus fill the letter, not giving the exact path of letters.as mentioned in my question i need this because of showing the drawing animation..any idea how it would be possible ?

Comment: Do you need one path for the whole string? Please elaborate a bit more.

Comment: ya one path. for eg: int the case of  letter 'O' , i need the path like single circle/ellipse ..

Comment: Maybe the path made with glyphs is not the best solution for your task. You always can construct any custom path using curves and lines: CGContextAddArc(), CGContextAddLines(), etc.

Comment: but its is not  a good method (not possible) to create entire string using CGContextAddArc(), CGContextAddLines(), etc

Comment: The path you have on the picture (1) consists of 11 lines, when (2) has only three. They are totally different. It is not easy to build your own one, you are right. I would try to find a wire font, maybe like Ambassador: http://new.myfonts.com/fonts/juraj-chrastina/ambassador/ or Shiva, it might give you the path you need.